# How to get id from dynamic url?

Tags: nuxt.js

We are using an email verification step when a user tries to sign up an new account. In the mail there's a link with a unique id `https://example.com/account/emailVerification?0cyYJMHush7kjJezyK3Qgu72uz1oARgPdleRJRtHHjk` where `0cyYJMHush7kjJezyK3Qgu72uz1oARgPdleRJRtHHjk` is the id.

In the component I want to extract the id to use in some logic:"

```
mounted () {
  console.log(window.$nuxt.$route)
},
```

[image]

There's a query object there but it looks like the actual id string is the name of query and the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Of course after doing the good old rubber ducky I found out that the url has to be a little bit different:

`https://example.com/emailVerification?id=0cyYJMHush7kjJezyK3Qgu72uz1oARgPdleRJRtHHjk`

So I added the `?id=0C...` now query has a id object with the id as a value.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties

You can have to your route queries with `$route.query.<your-query>`, so in your view, in your case, it will probably be something like: `this.$route.query.id`.

Otherwise, for params: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching